# Symfony2: Redis functions parameter count missmatch

Tags: php, symfony, redis

I am running a symfony 2.7 app which interacts with a redis server. The app is running on a Ubuntu Server 18.04. with php7.2.

I'm using the snc_redisbundle library for the interaction between symfony and redis. I'm basically only using the commands:
```

```
$redis->setEx(...); 
$redis->get(...);
```

When using one of these methods I get the following Warning (Stacktrace):

```
PHP Warning:  Redis::setex() expects exactly 3 parameters, 0 given in /vagrant/app/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php on line 6954
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /vagrant/app/console:0
PHP   2. JMS\JobQueueBundle\Console\Application->run() /vagrant/app/console:28
PHP   3. JMS\JobQueueBundle\Console\Application->doRun() /vagrant/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:114
PHP   4. JMS\JobQueueBundle\Console\Application->doRun() /vagrant/vendor/jms/job-queue-bundle/JMS/JobQueueBundle/Console/Application.php:45
PHP   5. JMS\JobQueueBundle\Console\Application->doRun() /vagrant/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:82
PHP   6. JMS\JobQueueBundle\Console\Application->doRunCommand() /vagrant/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:190
PHP   7. AppBundle\Command\ImportTransactionsCommand->run() /vagrant/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:850
PHP   8. AppBundle\Command\ImportTransactionsCommand->execute() /vagrant/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:238
PHP   9. Redis_000000001e6eb7de00000000076bcf86fcaf778105bfb1fa4a93de3bacb39221->setex() /vagrant/src/AppBundle/Command/ImportTransactionsCommand.php:240
PHP  10. Redis->setex() /vagrant/app/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php:6954
PHP Warning:  Redis::get() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /vagrant/app/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php on line 6944
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /vagrant/app/console:0
PHP   2. JMS\JobQueueBundle\Console\Application->run() /vagrant/app/console:28
PHP   3. JMS\JobQueueBundle\Console\Application->doRun() /vagrant/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:114
PHP   4. JMS\JobQueueBundle\Console\Application->doRun() /vagrant/vendor/jms/job-queue-bundle/JMS/JobQueueBundle/Console/Application.php:45
PHP   5. JMS\JobQueueBundle\Console\Application->doRun() /vagrant/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:82
PHP   6. JMS\JobQueueBundle\Console\Application->doRunCommand() /vagrant/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:190
PHP   7. AppBundle\Command\ImportTransactionsCommand->run() /vagrant/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:850
PHP   8. AppBundle\Command\ImportTransactionsCommand->execute() /vagrant/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:238
PHP   9. Redis_000000001e6eb7de00000000076bcf86fcaf778105bfb1fa4a93de3bacb39221->get() /vagrant/src/AppBundle/Command/ImportTransactionsCommand.php:334
PHP  10. Redis->get() /vagrant/app/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php:6944
```

I do not understand why it is complaining about the number of supplied parameters since I do supply the parameters in my code.

The warning refers to the file, appProdProjectContainer.php, but I cannot change the function in here since the file is auto-generated by symfony cache warmup.

Console Command code:

```
$redis = $this->container->get('snc_redis.clients.default');
$redis->setEx("shadow__".$pid, $lifeTime, 'created_at_'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s')); 
$expireValue = $redis->get($expireKey);
```

Hope you guys can help me find a solution, Thanks in advance

Comment: very strange... try with all lowercase `setex`  instead of `setEx`

Comment: @Matteo same result :-(